# clips: modifying assert's variable in antecedent

Tags: clips

I've been trying to modify one variable from one assert in the antecedent, but I haven't been able to do it.

In the consequent I can modify variables, with bind, assignments, etc. but I'd like to do the following:

```
(defrule test
  ?h<-(Currentposition ?x ?y)
  (not (Explored (+ ?x 1) ?y))
=> (whatever)
```

So, the problem is that I have a character moving through a map, and I want to explore unknown cells, so I want to go to them, and in order to do so, I mark them as Explored.

In the example, I want to check if the south cell has been explored, how can I do it? I add 1 to x because I move 1 row below, x-> rows, y-> columns

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use =, the return value constraint:

```
(defrule test
   ?h <- (Currentposition ?x ?y)
   (not =(Explored (+ ?x 1) ?y))
   =>)
```